# reducing cost of Authlogic/find in ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed that my AJAX calls on my website are slow, and looking at `NewRelic RPM` I've noticed that most of the cost comes from `Authlogic/find`.

I guess this is because rails needs to look up the user each time (even on AJAX calls), but 147 microseconds seems awfully slow.

```
Category    Segment     % Time      Avg Calls (per Txn)     Avg Exclusive Time (ms)
Custom       Authlogic/find      77      1.0     147
Controller  LikesController#toggle  13  1.0     25
Database    SQL - SHOW  4.9     1.5     9.3
Database    SQL - OTHER     1.1     3.7     2.1
ActiveRecord    User#find   0.8     1.0     1.5
View    application.html.haml Template  0.7     0.2     1.3
View    _like.html.haml Template    0.5     0.8     0.89
ActiveRecord    ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session#find    0.4     1.0     0.69
```

Here's my code:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  ## commented this part out in the hopes of reducing authlogic needs, since it's simple for me to check for current_user myself.

  # access_control do
  #   allow :admin
  #   allow logged_in, :to => [:toggle]
  # end
  before_filter :check_if_admin, :except => [:toggle]

  def index
    @likes = Like.all
  end

  def toggle
    if !current_user
      render :nothing => true and return
    end

    like = Like.find(:first, :conditions => "user_id = #{current_user.id} and likable_id = #{params[:likable_id]} and likable_type = '#{params[:likable_type]}'")
    if like != nil
      like.destroy
      @current_user_likes_likable = false
    else
      like = Like.new(:likable_id => params[:likable_id], :likable_type => params[:likable_type], :user => current_user)
      like.save
      @current_user_likes_likable = true
    end
    @likable_id = params[:likable_id]
    @likable_type = params[:likable_type]
    #@likable = Kernel.const_get(params[:likable_type]).find(params[:likable_id])
    render "shared/like"
  end
...
```

Also here's where current_user is defined in ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper :layout
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user, :current_user_is_admin

  private
    def current_user_session
      return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end
    def current_user
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using? If you have slow running queries the first thing to look at is [indexes on your database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_(database)). I don't know what SQL the find method is running, but that's a good place to start. Ensure that you have the correct indexes (you may need more than one) on the columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in another app. I've built a clean project using authlogic: http://github.com/josei/authlogic_rpm

Newrelic is installed and working, so you can quickly check authlogic's performance. As you can see, performance is quite ok (around 50ms with sqlite3), so the overhead must be somewhere else (maybe a plugin).